# Making Site Compatible looking good on Desktop and Mobile

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, mobile, primefaces

I am using Spring, JSF, primefaces, hibernate technologies on my website.

I build my site for desktop and now i have many user who enters from mobile devices, and i had many complaints that they cant see the things properly.

What can i use in this technology for making my site good looking in mobile like this template : http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/45559.html

This template has so good looking on each devices. I just wanted to show how i want my site to look on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

The technic you are looking for is called [Responsive Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design). In your case [PrimeFaces Mobile](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/mobile/index.xhtml) might be what you want.

Note: Mixing PrimeFaces with another css framework like Bootstrap or Foundation is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Except the Primefaces Mobile you can have a look at Responsive Design with CSS3 Media Queries: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries